# Accessing newly singed up user in Rails app using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am currently making Rails app using devise.
After a new user signs up, I need to access newly singed up user's information to run my customized function. 
However it seems like devise's `current_user` is nil since the user is not logged in yet until the user confirms the email.

I essentially just need to check whether user's `confirmed_at` is nil.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: can you not just run a db query like user = User.last ? (after save)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this in the `User` model with a callback:

```
# in app/model/user.rb (assuming you have a User model)
after_create :run_customized_function

private
  def run_customized_function
    # whatever need to be done with this user, for example: 
    # Rails.logger.info("User##{id} just signed up with email '#{email}'")
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Through this way, how do I access newly signed up user's information through devise?

Comment: The method `run_customized_function` is an instance method on a user. It has access to all the user's attributes (see `id` or `email` in the example). Can you please elaborate what information you need and what you mean by *through devise*.

Comment: oh never mind. I get what you are saying now. One more thing. I can get user's email right now. As soon as `run_customized_function` runs, I run a custom function in application controller. If I want to access the same user instance, what should I do? I am thinking about using `Rails.cache.save("user": self)` to save user instance in `run_customized_function` and retrieve from the application_controller but this looks sketchy. Could there be a better way?

Comment: It is hard to tell, because you didn't tell us what your method actually does. In theory I would prefer doing things in the model instead of in the controller. That makes it easier to test. Would you mind posting that method or telling us why you think you need to define that `run_customized_function` in your controller?

Comment: oh my bad. I have a function in application_controller called `home`. If current_user exists, then it renders Angular template. If not, it renders Rails template. When User signs up, the user is not considered signed in yet since the user is not confirmed. Thus, I need a way to find whether the user trying to log in is yet to be authenticated.